# Where Business Logic Should Go Where Database is not involved?

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are working on a web application. This application is based on PHP Codeigniter framework. I have some business logic where database is NOT involved at all. We are just processing client input parameter and returning results. We are not sure whether we should put this business logic (which is processing client input without database interaction) in Model or should we create library or helper?

Kindly suggest as per best coding practices.

Comment: Your data is client input, so it could be represented in models. And your data processing (business logic) could be stored in services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client input is the data here, not a database, the concept is still the same and so it should be handled in the models.

This is what CodeIgniters documentation says for models:

> Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in
>   your database. For example, let's say you use CodeIgniter to manage a
>   blog. You might have a model class that contains functions to insert,
>   update, and retrieve your blog data.
>   http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

But the concept applies to all data. Despite the CodeIgniter documentation.

> The central component, the model, consists of application data,
>   business rules, logic, and functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Models are to handle data, controllers essentially accept data for the models and pass/prepare it for the views.

Comment: I agree. Databases are related _only_ to _persistency_ of data, there are several aditional aspects that, as AJReading said, are part of Models.